# How do I Split a Cell With Multiple Delimiters and/or Strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I scraped table data from https://www.actionnetwork.com/ncaaf/public-betting
but it was a jumbled mess in one column, so I'm trying to clean it up after exporting to Excel:

I want to add a column `Matchups` and split out the two team names from the `Scheduled` column into their own rows if possible.

If I only split by 'PM' I get the 1st desired output on some, but I still have cells with the AM games, and I would like to split by that as well.

At that point, I'm not sure how to split to return the final desired output. Any ideas?

Before:

[image]

1st Desired Output:

[image]

Final Desired Output:

[image]

Thanks to all who take a look.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('ActionNetwork.xlsx')
df['Matchups']= df['Scheduled'].apply(lambda x: x.split('PM | AM')[-1])
print(df)
```

Comment: Figured out first part. Just added .split again for "AM" and got 1st desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to put the matchups back into the same `df`, the teams need to go into separate columns (otherwise it will throw an error about uneven row counts).

Instead of multiple splits, use a single [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the following patterns:

- `.*[AM|PM]`  -- match everything up to `AM`  or `PM`  (but don't capture it)
- `([0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+)` -- capture 1+ numbers and 1+ letters/spaces (away team)
- `([0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+)` -- capture 1+ numbers and 1+ letters/spaces (home team)

```
pattern = r'.*[AM|PM] ([0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+)([0-9]+[a-zA-Z ]+)'
df[['Away', 'Home']] = df['Scheduled'].str.extract(pattern)

#                                          Scheduled             Away          Home
# 0      Fri 10/29, 11:30 PM 113NavyNAVY114TulsaTLSA      113NavyNAVY  114TulsaTLSA
# 1       Sat 10/30, 2:00 AM 114UNLVUNLV116NevadaNEV      114UNLVUNLV  116NevadaNEV
# 2  Sat 10/30, 11:00 PM 110Ole MissMISS118AuburnAUB  110Ole MissMISS  118AuburnAUB
```

Comment: Only issue I'm running into with this is teams with a space return as Nans. 
Ex: 195Ole Miss returns the Away and Home columns as NAN

Comment: ah ok, try the updated `pattern`